# Windows 10 + Ubuntu dual boot - Windows can't boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a motherboard with UEFI (Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H with latest UEFI).
I installed Windows 10, then installed Ubuntu 17.04 with dual boot option.

Ubuntu would boot, but due to no overscan options working for my LCD TV, I went to boot Windows.  Windows proceeded to try to repair itself, and failed; startup repair fixes nothing.  I want to find out how to boot Windows without wiping the hard drive.

Comment: Did you turn off fast boot in windows?

Comment: Yes, and in the UEFI OS type is set to "Windows 8" (Options are "other" (basically BIOS-style compatibility mode), and "Windows 8 WHQL"

Comment: What error did windows show

Comment: First "Preparing automatic repair" then
"Your PC/device needs to be rapaired 0x000000e"

Comment: did you upgrade from win8 to win10. it appears the recovery partition is win8.....  grub doesn't launch win10 for you?

Comment: Grub does the same thing, and this System was setup with Windows 10 by me, it has never had Windows 8 installed.

Comment: If you have windows installation disc Try this:  boot from the disc and type Shift+F10 to get terminal then type bootrec /rebuildbcd

Comment: Just ran that, it didn't detect _any_ Windows installations.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to install boot-repair. type these commands in the terminal to install boot-repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

now launch the boot-repair by typing "boot-repair" in the terminal, Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs. i hope it will work. because it worked for me.

Comment: if you would like to read about boot-repair in detail then visit this web page [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair]

Comment: That didn't work, I'm going to try to rebuild the BCD.